# Publish a product page

Tags: moqui

We have a website on which we want to publish a product web page. I am aware in Moqui we can use `ViewAllow` and `PurchaseAllow` category to make a product visible/purchased on the website. But what is the best-practice to publish a webpage?

Answer (score 0):

Use `statusId` to indicating the status of the product.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. or please elaborate your code examples since its too short and heavy to understand